# Qt equivalent for a boost tokenizer expression/construction

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I am using Qt 4.8 on Ubuntu 14.04.
I am currently trying to port a Windows app... The author intensively used *boost* in the app code.
I already replaced many *boost*-calls with Qt equivalent constructions (I have zero experience with *boost*).
Now I stumbled upon this one:

```
string command;
...
boost::char_separator<char> sep(",\t\r ");
boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tokens(command, sep);
```

Is there a Qt equivalent for it?
I tried :

```
QStringList tokens = QString(command.data()).split(QRegExp("\\s+"));
```

but it doesn't seem to be quite ok...
1) first: it doesn't behave like original app.
2) second: I always get an empty token. Weird and I don't know **why**...!?!

Please can you give me some help or share some ideas in order to solve these issues?
Thanks in advance for your time and patience.

Comment: just a warning: not everything in boost has a qt alternative. Why do you need to replace boost with qt? It seems like a huge effort. Boost is cross-platform, and I would just use it as it is.

Comment: Now there are only a few _boost calls_ left to be converted... It is indeed a huge effort, but I have no choice, these are the requirements. For this one above: I'm pretty sure it can be done.

Comment: What about `split(QRegExp("[,\t\r ]"))` or `split(QRegExp("[,\t\r ]"), QString::SkipEmptyParts)`?

Comment: @BenjaminT: It works, the one with `QString::SkipEmptyParts`. Thanks, great!

Comment: @BenjaminT: Surely worth a little effort to post it as an answer. Thumb up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments to the question, the solution is to use:

```
split(QRegExp("[,\t\r ]"), QString::SkipEmptyParts)
```